# Iterate through complex object to set view model values

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Let's say the following complex Json response was sent by back by a remote service

```
 {
      "query": "search",
      "skills": {
           "skill": [
                "php",
                "java",
                "C#"
           ]
      },
      "results": [
           {
                "name": "jim",
                "dept": "technology"
           },
           {
                "name": "peter",
                "dept": "technology"
           }
      ]
 }
```

Its format is fixed and I've stored it as a String

```
 string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Res);
```

and I have a Response Model

```
public class Response 
{
    public string query { get; set; }       
    public Skill skills { get; set; }
    public List<Employees> results { get; set; }
}

public class Skill 
{
    public List<string> skill { get; set; }

}

public class Employees
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string dept { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a View Model

```
 public class EmployeeExperts {
      public List<EmployeeInfo> employee { get; set; }
 }

 public class EmployeeInfo {
      public string name { get; set; }
      public string dept { get; set; }
 }
```

and I have deserialized the response to the class

```
 var Obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonString);
```

How then would I iterate through Obj and hook it up, from the controller to my EmployeeExperts View Model?

e.g. EmployeeExperts.EmployeeInfo[0] = Response.results[0].name

I'm just trying to properly parse a response and show it on the view. Additionally, I've got another question - Is this the right way of doing all of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I noticed your `Employees` and `EmployeeInfo` is same, it does not need to.

You can change `EmployeeExperts` class as follows:

```
public class EmployeeExperts {
      public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
 }
```

And now you can write:

```
 var Obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(jsonString);
 var experts = new EmployeeExperts();

 // You can directly assign list like this and iterate through `experts.Employees` list
 experts.Employees = obj.results;
```

Note: I have not tested above code, you may need to cast results into `List<Employee>`.

> Additionally, I've got another question - Is this the right way of doing all of this?

I have used [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) for such object to object conversion. It is flexible and does handle 95% cases. In those 95% cases it saves a lot of your time that you otherwise spend in conversion.

Give it a try and see if serves your purpose.